# How to mock FileReader using jest

Tags: javascript, jestjs

I need to mock a function that uses `FileReader` using jest.
Specifically the function `readAsBinaryString` and `onload`.

I've created some code:

```
FileReader.readAsBinaryString = () => mock.mockReturnValue(null);
```

But it doesn't work.
How can I mock `FileReader` and your functions using jest?

Function to test:

```
handleFileUpload(event) {
  let reader = new FileReader();
  let file = event.target.files[0];

  reader.readAsBinaryString(file);

  reader.onload = () => {
    let base64String = btoa(reader.result);
    this.object.image = 
  };
},
```

Comment: You shouldn't read the file as a binaryString, use arrayBuffer or text

Answer (score 6):

You can use [jest.spyOn(object, methodName, accessType?)](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/jest-object#jestspyonobject-methodname-accesstype) to spy on `readAsBinaryString` method of `FileReader`. `readAsBinaryString` is an instance method, not static method of `FileReader` constructor. Besides, the return value of `readAsBinaryString` is `void`. So you can't mock a return value.

E.g.

`index.ts`:

```js
export function main() {
  const fr = new FileReader();
  const blob = new Blob();
  fr.readAsBinaryString(blob);
}
```

`index.spec.ts`, we need spy on `FileReader.prototype.readAsBinaryString`, since it's an instance method.

```js
import { main } from './';

describe('main', () => {
  test('should mock FileReader', () => {
    const readAsBinaryStringSpy = jest.spyOn(FileReader.prototype, 'readAsBinaryString');
    main();
    expect(readAsBinaryStringSpy).toBeCalledWith(new Blob());
  });
});
```

Unit test result with 100% coverage:

```sh
PASS  src/stackoverflow/58644737/index.spec.ts
  main
    ✓ should mock FileReader (10ms)

----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
File      |  % Stmts | % Branch |  % Funcs |  % Lines | Uncovered Line #s |
----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
All files |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
 index.ts |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        4.852s, estimated 9s
```

**Update**

`index.ts`:

```js
export class Component {
  object = {
    image: ''
  };
  handleFileUpload(event) {
    let reader = new FileReader();
    let file = event.target.files[0];

    reader.readAsBinaryString(file);

    reader.onload = () => {
      let base64String = btoa(reader.result as string);
      this.object.image = base64String;
    };

    return reader;
  }
}
```

`index.spec.ts`:

```js
import { Component } from './';

const cmp = new Component();

describe('main', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    jest.restoreAllMocks();
  });
  test('should test handle file upload correctly', () => {
    const mFile = new File(['go'], 'go.pdf');
    const mEvent = { target: { files: [mFile] } };
    const readAsBinaryStringSpy = jest.spyOn(FileReader.prototype, 'readAsBinaryString');
    const btoaSpy = jest.spyOn(window, 'btoa');
    const reader = cmp.handleFileUpload(mEvent);
    expect(reader).toBeInstanceOf(FileReader);
    if (reader.onload) {
      Object.defineProperty(reader, 'result', { value: 'gogo' });
      const mOnloadEvent = {} as any;
      reader.onload(mOnloadEvent);
      expect(btoaSpy).toBeCalledWith('gogo');
      expect(cmp.object.image).toBe(btoa('gogo'));
    }
    expect(readAsBinaryStringSpy).toBeCalledWith(mFile);
  });
});
```

Unit test result with 100% coverage:

```sh
 PASS  src/stackoverflow/58644737/index.spec.ts (7.328s)
  main
    ✓ should test handle file upload correctly (13ms)

----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
File      |  % Stmts | % Branch |  % Funcs |  % Lines | Uncovered Line #s |
----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
All files |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
 index.ts |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        8.78s
```

Source code: https://github.com/mrdulin/jest-codelab/tree/master/src/stackoverflow/58644737

Comment: thanks, but I need to mock onload from FileReader because I get base64 string from file inside.

Comment: @AjjjHsh Edit your question, add the code that your want to test

Comment: @AjjjHsh Update answer

Comment: can't instantiate Component.handleFileUpload. I'm using vue.js. handleFileUpload is a method

Answer (score 2):

I personally could not get any of the jest.spyOn() approaches to work in my Vue-test-utils setup, `jest.spyOn(FileReader.prototype, 'readAsDataURL');` kept generating the following error:
`Cannot spy the readAsDataURL property because it is not a function; undefined given instead`

If it can help anyone else having issues with this, I managed to successfully mock the FileReader prototype using the following:

```
Object.defineProperty(global, 'FileReader', {
  writable: true,
  value: jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => ({
    readAsDataURL: jest.fn(),
    onLoad: jest.fn()
  })),
})
```

Then in my test, I was able to test the file input onChange method (which was making use of the FileReader) by mocking the event and triggering it manually like this:

```
const file = {
  size: 1000,
  type: "audio/mp3",
  name: "my-file.mp3"
}
const event = {
  target: {
    files: [file]
  }
}
wrapper.vm.onChange(event)
```

Answer (score 1):

I've made some progress:

```
const dummy = {
     readAsBinaryString: jest.fn(),
        onload: function(){
          wrapper.vm.object.image = '...'
        }
     }
   }

window.FileReader = jest.fn(() => dummy)
```

The problem is that onload isn't get mocked on real call:

```
reader.onload = function() {
}
```

Only when I call

```
reader.onload()
```

So I think onload declaration on dummy is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to call the onload event as a part of readAsText You can use following code

```
const readAsTextMock = jest.fn();
jest.spyOn(global, 'FileReader').mockImplementation(function () {
  const self = this;
  this.readAsText = readAsTextMock.mockImplementation(() => {
    self.onload({ target: { result: "file read result mock" } });
  });
});
```

Comment: This works however the const self = this is unnecessary since the fat arrow function will bind the `this` for you. It is important to use `function ()` at the high level though.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty late comment, but for what it's worth, this his how I was able to mock FileReader:

First, I created a function that returned new FileReader() instead of calling it directly.

```
export function fileReaderWrapper() {
  return new FileReader();
}
```

Then the code that needs file reader can call that function

```
const reader = fileReaderWrapper();
reader.readAsDataURL(file);
while (reader.readyState !== 2) {
  yield delay(100);
}
const imageData = reader.result;
```

Now my test can use jest to mock everything I check.. and I no longer have to use a timeout in my test to wait on FileReader to finish reading a file.

```
jest.mock('~/utils/helper', () => ({
  fileReaderWrapper: jest.fn().mockReturnValue({
    readAsDataURL: (file: File) => {
      return;
    },
    readyState: 2,
    result: 'data:image/png;base64,undefined',
  }),
}));
```